# При сортировке строк в QTableWidget пропадают данные в некоторых столбцах, как исправить?

Tags: python, pyqt5, сортировка, qtablewidget

Имеется 2 таблицы `category` и `subcategory`. Таблица `subcategory` заполняется данными на основании выбранной строки в таблицы `category`.

При нажатии на столбец заголовка таблицы `subcategory`, происходит сортировка данных в таблице, но после выбора другой строки в таблицы `category`, пропадают данные в некоторых ячейках столбцов 1 и 2 таблицы `subcategory`, или не соответствуют данным столбца 0.

Как исправить, теряюсь в догадках(

Данные `category_data` и `subcategory_data` приведены для примера, на деле использую данные полученные с SQLite.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidgetItem

import Kaban.test.sort.test_sort as my_gui

category_data = {
    ("Категория 1", "100", "300.00"),
    ("Категория 2", "1000", "200.00"),
    ("Категория 3", "20", "120.00")
}

subcategory_data = {
    "Категория 1":
    {
        ("Ч1", "5", "100000000001"),
        ("Ч2", "6", "100000000002"),
        ("Ч3", "7", "100000000003"),
        ("Ч4", "8", "100000000004")
    },
    "Категория 2":
        {
            ("C1", "5", "200000000001"),
            ("C2", "4", "200000000002"),
            ("C3", "3", "200000000003"),
            ("C5", "1", "200000000005")
        },
    "Категория 3": {
        ("Ф1", "50", "300000000001"),
        ("Ф2", "40", "300000000002"),
        ("Ф5", "10", "300000000005")
    }
}


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget, my_gui.Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.fill_table_category()
    
        self.category.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.fill_table_subcategory)
        self.category.selectRow(0)

    def fill_table_category(self):
        self.category.setRowCount(0)

        for row in enumerate(category_data, 0):
            self.category.insertRow(row[0])
            for column in range(self.category.columnCount()):
                self.category.setItem(row[0], column, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[1][column])))

        self.category.setSortingEnabled(True)

    def fill_table_subcategory(self):
        self.subcategory.setRowCount(0)

        data_for_subcategory = self.get_selected_category()

        for row in enumerate(subcategory_data[data_for_subcategory]):
            self.subcategory.insertRow(row[0])
            for column in range(self.subcategory.columnCount()):
                self.subcategory.setItem(row[0], column, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[1][column])))

        self.subcategory.setSortingEnabled(True)

    def get_selected_category(self):
        row_index = self.category.currentRow()
        selected_category = self.category.item(row_index, 0).text()
        return selected_category


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: Получаю после сортировки:]

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос как выглядит `subcategory_data`?

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хм, интересный эффект, который воспроизводится и в `PySide2`, и `PySide6`. Исправляется просто выключением сортировки перед добавлением данных:

```
def fill_table_subcategory(self):
    self.subcategory.setRowCount(0)

    data_for_subcategory = self.get_selected_category()
    
    self.subcategory.setSortingEnabled(False) # <- вот этой строкой

    for row in enumerate(subcategory_data[data_for_subcategory]):
        self.subcategory.insertRow(row[0])
        for column in range(self.subcategory.columnCount()):
            self.subcategory.setItem(row[0], column, QTableWidgetItem(str(row[1][column])))

    self.subcategory.setSortingEnabled(True)
```

Comment: Alexander Chernin спасибо вам огромное! сколько времени потратил... И не мог сделать такую простую вещь